# How to upload local files to S3 quickly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an angular app. I need to upload it to S3. I've tired to use AWS Console cause I have a lot of directories. How can I upload all my files  quickly. Thanks.

Is it possible to send all files in one time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
aws s3 cp --recursive <localfolderpath> s3://<bucketname>/<key>/
```

Comment: <key>   -   Access key ID ?

Comment: Could you help me please? I got this errors - An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Comment: @DmitryGrinko you have access permission issue.

Comment: your accesskey/secretkey user does not have `s3: PutObject` permission.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest way is using [aws-cli](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html).
Like said [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/using-s3-commands.html):

> The sync command has the following form. Possible source-target
>   combinations are:
>
> Local file system to Amazon S3 Amazon S3 to local file system Amazon
>   S3 to Amazon S3
>
> `$ aws s3 sync <source> <target> [--options]`
>
> The following example synchronizes the contents of an Amazon S3 folder
>   named path in my-bucket with the current working directory. s3 sync
>   updates any files that have a different size or modified time than
>   files with the same name at the destination. The output displays
>   specific operations performed during the sync. Notice that the
>   operation recursively synchronizes the subdirectory MySubdirectory and
>   its contents with s3://my-bucket/path/MySubdirectory.
>
> `$ aws s3 sync . s3://my-bucket/path`
>
> upload: MySubdirectory\MyFile3.txt to s3://my-bucket/path/MySubdirectory/MyFile3.txt
>
> upload: MyFile2.txt to s3://my-bucket/path/MyFile2.txt
>
> upload: MyFile1.txt to s3://my-bucket/path/MyFile1.txt

You can also check the aws-sdk from [this docs](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/):

There is a section with all availables languages and platforms for using the SDK:
[image: SDK]

And [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-examples.html) are some examples of using the sdk for Javascript with Amazon S3

Comment: I got this errors - "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied" while I try to use aws s3 .... How to add permissions  s3: PutObject ?

Comment: Did you configure the right user with S3 privileges on aws-cli ?

Comment: My user has all permissions. I have found a solution. I should create s3 bucket via console with all permissions and then use this command. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also upload directly from Webpack with [webpack-s3-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/s3-plugin-webpack) or [s3-website](https://github.com/klaemo/s3-website).

```
var config = {
  plugins: [
    new S3Plugin({
      // Exclude uploading of html
      exclude: /.*\.html$/,
      // s3Options are required
      s3Options: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        region: 'us-west-1'
      },
      s3UploadOptions: {
        Bucket: 'MyBucket'
      }
    })
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some options to allow upload files to S3 bucket:

- Via AWS console: This option quite straightforward, from AWS console -> go to S3 bucket -> locate the bucket want to upload -> go to folder you want to store the files there -> Click add file/ add folder -> drag and drop file to the placeholder -> click Upload.
- Using AWS cli (version 2 is good): This option require access to the aws s3 using cli mean that you have to config credential at local machine.Then run aws commands:

  aws s3 cp /path/to/local/file s3://bucket-name/path/to/s3/location/
  aws s3 cp /galireview/galireview-demobucket-file s3://galireview-demobucket

or for upload folders:

```
aws s3 cp /path/to/local/folder s3://bucket-name/path/to/s3/location/ --recursive
aws s3 cp /galireview/galireview-demobucket s3://galireview-demobucket --recursive
```

- Using AWS SDK: This option is used for writing scripts or application. This is an example of using Python:

```
    # Import the boto3 library
    import boto3
    
    # Replace these values with your AWS credentials and S3 bucket name
    aws_access_key_id = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
    aws_secret_access_key = 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
    bucket_name = 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME'
    
    # The local file path that you want to upload
    local_file_path = '/path/to/local/file.txt'
    
    # The S3 key (file name) under which the file will be stored
    s3_key = 'folder/file.txt'
    
    # Create an S3 client
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    
    # Upload the file to S3
    try:
        s3.upload_file(local_file_path, bucket_name, s3_key)
        print(f"File {local_file_path} successfully uploaded to S3 bucket {bucket_name} as {s3_key}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error uploading file to S3: {e}")
```

For more information please refer to the link: [How to upload data from local machine to Amazon S3](https://www.galireview.com/blog/how-to-upload-data-from-local-machine-to-amazon-s3/)